# How to add HTTP proxy to JAX-WS?

Tags: java, http, proxy, cxf, jax-ws

I have a WSDL file which I've turned into Java code by using WSDL2Java inside SoapUI, it works fine, but now I need to add my company's proxy to it, so every SOAP http request would go through it (but not other http requests).

I've looked through multiple threads concerning the same issue and found these options:

1. system wide proxy by adding

   ```
   System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
   System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", "10.10.10.10");
   System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", "8080");
   ```

   which doesn't work for me, since it affect the whole jvm.
2. adding the following code

   ```
   HelloService hello = new HelloService();
   HelloPortType helloPort = cliente.getHelloPort();
   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(helloPort);
   HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
   http.getClient().setProxyServer("proxy");
   http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(8080);
   http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName("user proxy");
   http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword("password proxy");
   ```

   which I don't get how to use. My generated code doesn't have any traces of **org.apache.cxf**, only **javax.xml.ws**.
3. Adding this to my port configuration:

   ```
   ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("http.proxyHost", "proxy@example.com");
   ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("http.proxyPort", "80");
   ```

   Here I use a random non-existing proxy and expect to get an error of any sort(timeout, invalid proxy, etc.), but instead it goes through without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example without using 3rd party libraries.

> https://github.com/schuch/jaxws-proxy-example/blob/master/jaxws-client-with-proxy/src/main/java/ch/schu/example/helloworld/Client.java

```
package ch.schu.example.helloworld;

import java.net.ProxySelector;

import ch.schu.example.hello.HelloImpl;
import ch.schu.example.hello.HelloImplService;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProxySelector.setDefault(new MyProxySelector());

        HelloImplService service = new HelloImplService();
        HelloImpl hello = service.getHelloImplPort();
        System.out.println(hello.sayHello("Howard Wollowitz"));
    }

}
```

> https://github.com/schuch/jaxws-proxy-example/blob/master/jaxws-client-with-proxy/src/main/java/ch/schu/example/helloworld/MyProxySelector.java

```
package ch.schu.example.helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyProxySelector extends ProxySelector {

    @Override
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) 
    {
        System.out.println("select for " + uri.toString());
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9999));
        ArrayList<Proxy> list = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
        list.add(proxy);
        return list;   
    }

    @Override
    public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Connection to " + uri + " failed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this change proxy for the whole JVM ?

Comment: @aleksandrs ```public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) ``` takes a uri param. So I think you can return empty proxy list except for the target url you want to proxy. May be you do some url pattern matching inside that method

Answer (score 0):

Im found an example near your thrid solution, on your samples it be:

```
HelloImplService service = new HelloImplService();
HelloImpl hello = service.getHelloImplPort();
((BindingProvider) client).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://proxyIp:proxyPort");
hello.method(var1, var2);
```

You can look at the current endpoint address by:

```
System.out.println(((BindingProvider) hello).getRequestContext().get(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY));
```

I found this examples there: [*Changing WSDL url ( endpoint) in JAX-WS client*](https://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/04/changing-wsdl-url-endpoint-in-jax-ws.html?m=1)

Btw, i have the same problem, but in my case wsdl from my server have 127.0.0.1 endpoint address and i need to replace it. And this solution works on my case.
Maybe you just put a wrong properties...